# File created by writing contents of createReadStream does not match the original data

Tags: node.js

I expected that the code below would work. I am doing a basic sanity check to test whether I can read a file into a readStream, preserving the encoding and then write it out to a file. My expectation was that the resulting file would be the same as the file that I read the data from but this seems to not be the case.

My code is

```
const zipPath = path.join(__dirname, 'inputFile.zip')

        const rs = fs.createReadStream(zipPath, { encoding: 'ascii' }) // yes it is ascii
        let fileData = ''
        rs.on('data', chunk => fileData += chunk)
        rs.on('end', () => { 
            console.log("data written got ", fileData)
            // now test making a file from this
            fs.writeFile('./outputFile.zip', fileData, 'ascii', (err) => { 
                if (err) console.error(err)
                console.log("WRITTEN")
            })
        })
```

Currently what happens is that I can't unzip the resulting file.

Could someone let me know what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

guess it had to do with encodings... this was more or less of a sanity check and it looks like just using `pipe` without encoding works fine...

```
const rs = fs.createReadStream(zipPath) // , { encoding: ENCODING })
        const ws = fs.createWriteStream('./output.zip') // , { encoding: ENCODING })
        rs.pipe(ws)
```